# Setting Key Usage attributes with Makecert

Tags: certificate, biztalk, makecert

Is it possible to set Key Usage attributes using makecert, or any other tool I can use to generate my own test certificates?

The reason I'm interested is that certificates used for BizTalk Server AS2 transport require a key usage of Digital Signature for signing and Data Encipherment or Key Encipherment for encryption/decryption, and I want to play around with this feature.

I see how to set *enhanced* key usage attributes with makecert, but not key usage.

Comment: I think you are looking for `-sky` option

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can use the -eku option to specify the key usage to your certificate.

See details here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa386968(VS.85).aspx

Comment: -eku lets you set *extended* key usages, not key usages.

Comment: Hum, i see... In that case i suggest you try to use Openssl to generate your cert. I don´t know the answer for your concrete problem using openssl but it is a powerfull tool (better than makecert in my opinion). I suggest you to add the "openssl" flag to your question and change the title to "makecert/Openssl". Perhaps that way you will get more helpfull answers. Regard

Answer (score 7):

While you cannot make a self-signed cert and set the Enhanced Key Usage parameters using `makecert` I thought I'd save everyone the trouble of trying to use go down the path of using OpenSSL to generate a cert on Windows. Instead, you can use `certreq` (which is available if you already have `makecert`) and fashion your own request to set the required parameters.

For example, this sets up a cert with an EKU of Document Encryption (1.3.6.1.4.1.311.80.1) and key usages of Key Encipherment and Data Encipherment.

Create a new file, `MyCert.inf`:

```
[Version]
Signature = "$Windows NT$"

[Strings]
szOID_ENHANCED_KEY_USAGE = "2.5.29.37"
szOID_DOCUMENT_ENCRYPTION = "1.3.6.1.4.1.311.80.1"

[NewRequest]
Subject = "cn=me@example.com"
MachineKeySet = false
KeyLength = 2048
KeySpec = AT_KEYEXCHANGE
HashAlgorithm = Sha1
Exportable = true
RequestType = Cert

KeyUsage = "CERT_KEY_ENCIPHERMENT_KEY_USAGE | CERT_DATA_ENCIPHERMENT_KEY_USAGE"
ValidityPeriod = "Years"
ValidityPeriodUnits = "1000"

[Extensions]
%szOID_ENHANCED_KEY_USAGE% = "{text}%szOID_DOCUMENT_ENCRYPTION%"
```

Just set the `Subject` to whatever you need.

Then run:

```
certreq -new MyCert.inf MyCert.cer
```

This will generate the public key (X509 cert) and install it to your Current User personal store on the machine. You can export it from there if you want.

I used this to generate a certificate for encrypting PowerShell DSC, for testing.

[image: Example cert]

For more details: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296456.aspx#BKMK_New

Comment: with `makecert` you can use `-eku` to set extended key usage, but I was looking for a way to set two or more extended key usage.

Comment: This approach got me around the 'Invalid provider type specified' error I got when using `New-SelfSignedCertificate`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Digital Signature, Data Encipherment and Key Encipherment can be add by using the PowerShell Cmdlet `New-SelfSignedCertificate`. One of the `New-SelfSignedCertificate` Parameters is `KeyUsage`where you can add DigitalSignature, DataEncipherment and KeyEncipherment.

[New-SelfSignedCertificate](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh848633) is described on technet (https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh848633)

Sample:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -Subject "CN=sample.com" -KeyUsage DataEncipherment, KeyEncipherment, DigitalSignature -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2,1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1") -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My"
```

The sample covers client authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2) and server authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1) and creates the certificate at the current user store under my.

The used object identifiers in the sample are mentioned in RFC 3280 within section "4.2.1.13  Extended Key Usage".

Comment: I wish I could give this 1000 upvotes. After a day of messing about with makecert and openssl this solved the problem for me.

Comment: FYI, OID 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2, and 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 are meant for SSL Client, and Server Authentication, the `-TextExtension` OID for data encipherment is tenuous at best and depends on the platform. Microsoft Crypto 2 file system data encipherment appears to be `1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.4`

Comment: @Reahreic "3" ist for code signing, server authentication is "1". I've updated my answer by adding the according RFC and to be more clear on this. 
None of OIDs used in the sample is platform specific. FYI Extended key usage can be found within ISO/IEC 9594-8 (2001).

Comment: @Florian You're correct, I must have fat fingered that when I typed the comment. Thx for the RFC and ISO refs. I'll take a deeper look into those as I'd only been leveraging `https://oidref.com/` to locate them and was having difficulties locating a File Encipherment OID for offline file en/decipherment.

Answer (score 0):

MakeCert doesn't let you specify key usage, only extended key usage.  I think you need a CA to create a broader certificate.

You can setup your own CA with ubuntu server.  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04